# MVC login if cookie exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know much about web authorization, but there is one page which after login into gives the user coockie of name AUTH_WEBSITE, and this website redirects to my website which is mvc. Now I would like to only check if this user has that auth cookie and if it has, then I would like to authorize it in my website as well.

Now, I assume that checking cookies this way and givin admin rights based on cookie is NOT safe because other user can create this cookie for him self right ? so what would be better ?

And what is best place in mvc to check if other user is already authorized or has this cookie to prevent forcing user to click login button ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can use 2 ways:

1. When you create your custom cookie, use **encryption methods**. Encrypt user's role, password, even id etc. So other people can not decrypt them all to create other legal cookie.
2. For security, the best way is that to `check user is exist in system or not in every action start`. In your Authorize attribute, take values from cookie and check user, if it just exist continue, else alert : cookie values are wrong.